# How to bind specific source IP address using Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession

Tags: c++, ssl, network-programming, poco, poco-libraries

I have a https client that can run on one of two redundant hosts. Would like the host that is the 'Active' client host to use a specific IP address as the source address so that traffic appears to be coming from one source. Low level OS network setup to allow this is all in place. Our https client is built using the Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession class.

From reading about this situation binding the shared source IP address to the client socket is the standard solution. Attempted the following code:

```
// set the shared IP address and use 0 (represents wildcard) for port
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa = Poco::Net::SocketAddress(ipAddress, 0);

// bind the shared IP address to the socket
Poco::Net::SecureStreamSocket sss;
sss.impl()->bind(sa);

Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(sss);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as the bind() is throwing Poco::InvalidAccessException and exception message is "Cannot bind() a SecureStreamSocketImpl".  Looked at the Poco source and bind() is just throwing this exception. Seems to not be allowed.

How to make this work with Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession class?

Is it even possible to make it work with this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible - there is a [pending issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/1475) for it. It will be done eventually but currently there's no timeframe.

Comment: Got it done for IPv4.  My first contribution to Poco library.  It will be in Poco 2.0.0 if all goes well.

Comment: Here is the link to Poco project with some additional info.  https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/pull/2078